# JavaFX 2.0 vs Qt for cross platform stand-alone application

Tags: java, c++, cross-platform, qt, javafx

I need a bit of advice from you developers who deal with cross-platform applications (specifically programs with a GUI).

I will be creating an application soon that needs to be cross-platform and so I have done some preliminary research on two different frameworks: JavaFX 2.0 and Qt.

Honestly, both would more than suit my needs.  So then I asked myself why I would choose one over the other (SPOILER ALERT: I don't know the answer :P ).  I do know that JavaFX 2.0 is rather new (as of 2012) and is not fully supported across platforms, but it will be eventually.

The question I pose is this: which one of these would you use for a cross-platform application, and what criteria did you look at when making that decision?

Thank you for taking the time to read this!  :)

Comment: Please let me know why, if you provide a down vote :)

Comment: I didnt down vote, but without describing the types of functionality your application has (ie, do you need high-end 3d graphics?), or mentioning the specific platforms you're interested in, you're limiting people's ability to help you.

Comment: The ongoing trend of answers for this kind of question are "whatever technology you and your team are familiar with" - and for good reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So we did an analysis of the two (+ HTML 5) for our purposes and found that JavaFX narrowly won out due to our familiarity with Java and Java based tooling and support stacks.

Our methodology was to list 20 criteria and rank each technology out of 10 for each.

For example, i18n, ease of hiring, x-platform support, mobile support, strength of commnuity, depth of tooling etc

Comment: Thank you for this!  Though I think it would be nice to know both, I think that I too will dive more into JavaFX (at least for this project).